# Line2D Java - Get coordinates where y = value?

Tags: java, 2d, line, coordinate

Given a line segment defined by (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), find the location on the line where y = a certain value.

I understand I could obtain the equation of the line, then solve using simultaneous equations, but is this possible using Line2D or any other Java classes?

Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated!

Kelvin.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's anything in the Java API to actually calculate the intersection. The closest you can get, I think, is to use Line2D to test whether the line segment intersects the (vertical) line *y* = *k* for some constant *k*:

```
Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2);
if (line.intersectsLine(Double.MIN_VALUE, k, Double.MAX_VALUE, k)) {
    double x = (x2 - x1) * (k - y1) / (y2 - y1);
    // intersection is at (x, k)
} else {
    // intersection is outside extend of the line segment
}
```

However, it would probably be more efficient to just check that `y1 != y2`, compute the intersection, and then check whether the *x* coordinate is in the range [x1, x2].

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest apache commons math for tasks like this.

http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/index.html

There are a number of ways you can do this. One way would be

```
org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.Line lineOne = new org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.Line(p,angle);

org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.Line horizontalLine = new org.apache.commons.math3.geometry.euclidean.twod.Line(new vector2d(0,yToSolveFor),pi/2);

Vector2D intersection=lineOne.intersect(horizontalLine);
intersection.getX(); // The answer
```